# Past participle as adjective without verb 'to be'

Tags: grammaticality, past-participles, whiz-deletion

Looking at the clause

> "... to talk to two separate people or groups involved in a
>   disagreement"

is the word 'involved' an adjective here? If it is, shouldn't it be 'that are involved'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implicit "which is"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113309/implicit-which-is). Traditional grammar regards the (often totally acceptable) shorter form as a 'reduced relative clause'.

Comment: I think that is it. Thank you!

Comment: There are many posts here addressing the topic; search for "reduced relative clause" (and be aware that some grammars regard the term as inaccurate and explain the shorter forms differently).