# English rule for ending past participle?

Tags: grammar

I have two examples of ending past versions. My question is `Are there any good ones left` is as same as `Are there any good ones which are left` and we omit `which are` there? Which English rule is that?

Examples:

- Are there any good ones **left**?
- The items **described** below are eligible:

Comment: These are the examples:  
Are there any good ones left?  
The items are eligible described below

Comment: Are there any good ones **left**? = Are there any good ones *that are* **left**? -> **Left** is the past participle of a passive construction. ++ “*The items are eligible **described** below:*” This seems to be substandard English. You probably mean “The items **described** below are eligible: = “The items *that are **described** below* are eligible:” **described** is also the past participle of a passive construction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implicit 'which is', 'which are'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113309/implicit-which-is-which-are). Looking up 'post-modifier', 'reduced relative' here leads to many similar questions. // Note that one often has to guess at the deleted words. 'good ones _that you have_ left'?

Comment: When we say, "The items described below..." it can have more than one connotation, like: The items that are described below...; The items that have been described below...; The items that were described below..., The items that will be described below... It leaves enough confusion on what is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence *Are there any good ones left* is an example of *a reduced relative clause*.

*The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* (p353) defines a *reduced clause as:*

> a shortened clause, particularly a non-finite or verbless clause with
>   a postmodifying function that can be interpreted as a relative clause
>   with its relative pronoun and finite verb omitted, e.g.
>
> - Anyone scared of heights is advised not to attempt to climb this
>     tower. (= Anyone *who is* scared of heights ...)

The general term for the omission of words that are recoverable by the listener or reader is *ellipsis*.

---

Note: Expanding the last sentence *The items are eligible described below*  to include the pronoun and verb results in:

- *The items are eligible which are described below*.

The expansion is itself of dubious grammaticality. The original sentence is of certain ungrammaticality.

Comment: +1 for the interesting spotlight on how native speakers might *almost* be prepared to accept the "non-reduced" version of the relative clause, but would have no qualms about dismissing the "reduced" version out of hand.